# StructureMap Add Multiple Instances Not working

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I'm trying to add multiple instances of a type to structure map using [StructureMap, NHibernate and multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930931/structuremap-nhibernate-and-multiple-databases) as a source of my design

Here is how I add them in my Registry:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings location in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            For<INHibernateSessionFactory>()
                .Add(x => new NHibernateSessionFactory(location.Name, GetSessionFactory(location.ConnectionString)));
        }
```

And then in my AppSessionFactory:

```
 public AppSessionFactory(IEnumerable<NHibernateSessionFactory> factories)
    {
        _factories = new List<INHibernateSessionFactory>(factories);
    }
```

Neither that or this work:

```
_factories = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<INHibernateSessionFactory>().ToList();
```

Both calls return two of the same object, same location and same SessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but this might have to do with the way that you're accessing a modified closure.

I would try creating a locally scoped copy of your variable like so:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings location in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    ConnectionStringSettings localLocation = location;
    For<INHibernateSessionFactory>()
        .Add(x => new NHibernateSessionFactory(localLocation.Name, GetSessionFactory(localLocation.ConnectionString)));
}
```